# How can I center a fixed DIV that with auto WIDTH?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to center the div (class .popin) that wraps the images when clicking on them at bottom of each article on this website:

[Click for website](http://bit.ly/O6vOSu)

The DIV's POSITION is FIXED and it's WIDTH is set to AUTO because I want it to change depending on the size of the image.

Comment: It'd be a lot easier to answer your question if you showed us an example of what you're asking, rather than linking to an entire website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using CSS3 it's pretty easy:

**HTML**

```
<div class="popin">
  POPIN
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.popin {
  position: fixed;
  left: 50%;
  height: 100px;
  background: #fc0;

  -webkit-transform: translate3d(-50%,0,0);
  -moz-transform: translate3d(-50%,0,0);
  -ms-transform: translate3d(-50%,0,0);
  -o-transform: translate3d(-50%,0,0);
  transform: translate3d(-50%,0,0);
}
```

look browser support for [translate3d](http://caniuse.com/transforms3d)

Comment: @Farnabax, it works thank you, what does translate3d actually do ?